# JavaScript 'function undefined' error working with jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying just to understand an error completely because sometimes I can get around it and other times I can't. I've tried just writing a function:

```
function toggleButton() {
}
```

But I get the same error. This is the .js sample.

```
var checkBox = document.getElementById("chkMyBox"); 

 checkBox.onclick = function toggleButton(e, obj1) 
 {    
var btnElement = document.getElementById("btnMyButton");
    if(btnElement != null) {
        alert("Element not null");
    if(e.target.checked && obj1 != null) {
        alert("Checking check " + obj1.checked);
         if(obj1.checked == true && btnElement.getAttribute('disabled') == false){
            btnElement.getAttribute('disabled') = false;
        } else {
                btnElement.getAttribute('disabled') = true;
        } 
    }
  }  
}
```

Here's the html:

```
<form id="frmCheckBox">
   <input type="checkbox" id="chkMyBox" />    
   <button id="btnMyButton" disabled>I'm a Button</button>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Arandolph0/h8Re6/3/

Comment: First off, your HTML is wrong. You try to reference the checkbox by ID but you've never given it an ID.

Comment: You're not getting an element by ID. You're trying to get an element by it's name.

Comment: Please don’t correct the code after some people post answers, it makes it very hard to follow.

Comment: @April - Your original code had several issues that needed to be resolved. Your edit had nothing to do with your original post, thus making some answers useless.

Answer (score 5):

Change this line which uses `name`:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chkMyBox" />
```

into using `id` instead:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkMyBox" />
```

Alternatively you could use:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByName('chkMyBox');
var element = elements[0]; //first element with that name in the array
```

or

```
var element = document.getElementsByName('chkMyBox')[0];
```

**Update (as OP changed the code from the original question)**:

```
function toggleButton(e, obj1)
```

This won't work as there is only a single argument given to the callback function (`e`).
Use `e.target` to get the element.

Comment: He should keep the name on it. Removing the name can lead to unexpected results.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to get an element by its name. You'd have to do:

```
var checkBox = document.getElementsByName('chkMyBox')[0];
```

Or, if you prefer by id. Just add `id="chkMyBox"` to your checkbox input.

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems here.

1) You try to get the button by using `getElementById` but your element has no id. The easiest fix is to fix your markup.

`<input type="checkbox" name="chkMyBox" id="chkMyBox" />`

2) Your event handler takes two parameters. When attaching the handler via the DOM, only the event gets passed to your handler. Therefore `obj1` will always be `undefined`. You need to get the checkbox element from the `e` parameter.

```
checkBox.onclick = function(e) {
    var obj1 = e.target;
    // rest of handler
}
```

3) You shouldn't use `getAttribute` to check for the element being disabled/enabled. It will give you the text value of the attribute which is an empty string. Instead, use the boolean property that the DOM gives you:

```
// toggle the disabled attribute
obj1.disabled = !obj1.disabled;
```